# XCode 4.6.3 request timed out

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I get an error "Request timed out".  Even when XCode is idle, this sometimes pops up and I dont know what it is doing to complain about timing out.

Any ideas?  This happened after I upgraded to 4.6.3 but I don't know if thats related.

Comment: Are you building, running or testing when yous get this error..... Or even if you are not doing anything, it happens?

Comment: I think I'm doing nothing when it happens.  Not sure what is running to cause it to come up with this message.

Answer (score 0):

Check the downloads tab under preferences and uncheck the box: "Check for and install updates automatically".

Comment: That was checked, and iOS 6 Simulator is waiting to be installed.  I will give your suggestion a try.